# fopen_s won't open some path with accents?

Tags: c++

I can't open a file with name containing accents using fopen_s.
The name of the file is stored inside a char* (example: LÃÂ©gendes.txt") and I just do that:

```
fopen_s(&pFile, path, "rb")
```

It works for a file without accents but returns ENOENT for file names with them.

In fact the actual file name is "LÃ©gendes.txt" and I don't have control on that because it is produced by the library I have no control over...

I tried with wfopen_s and wchar* with the same result.
Also, another library is able to open the file by using the filename I stored.

Comment: Have you tried to read directory listing and compare filesystem encodings visible to your file browser and to system API? Properly entring or copying Unicode character is extremely difficult, so first test file existance with access() then blame fopen.

Comment: Basilevs sorry I mean about the code I provided it return 0 which means fopen_s does not return 0...

Comment: It returns ENOENT, it just doesn't find the file.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file using an absolute pathname?

Comment: Which library opens file successfully? Could the two be from the same vendor?

Comment: Hi ! did you find a solution ? i've got the same problem, my client uploads file in the wordpress media directory, which is stored with the french accent, like 'é'. But when i try to fopen this file, it doesn't work.